# Iferror in case of negative date doesn't apply in excell

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have two date like this:

[image]

In case of negative time-error ,I want to subtract them reverse but it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: It's not an error, it's just a negative number. It's the cell format that is the issue. Just test for D6 being greater than D5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error, when you have a negative time or it's to long, Excel show this information like this (############).

In that case it's better use a normal condition like this:

```
=If(D5-D6<0; D6-D5; D5-D6)
```

In this case you have a correct result.